# How to store a big numpy array in a zip archive in Python 3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, zip

I need to downport my code from Python 3.6 to Python 3.5.

I have changed:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(fh,
                     mode="w",
                     compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED,
                     allowZip64=True) as zf:
    with zf.open(k + '.npy',
                 mode='w',
                 force_zip64=True) as buf:
        np.lib.npyio.format.write_array(buf,
                                        np.asanyarray(v),
                                        allow_pickle=False)
```

to:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(fh,
                     mode="w",
                     compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED,
                     allowZip64=True) as zf:
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    np.lib.npyio.format.write_array(buf,
                                    np.asanyarray(v),
                                    allow_pickle=False)
    zf.writestr(k + '.npy',
                buf.getvalue())
```

When data is big enough, I get `OverflowError: Size does not fit in an unsigned int` from stdlib (`zipfile.py`).

How can I store big NumPy array in a zip archive?

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir='',
                                 prefix='_tmp_',
                                 suffix='.npy') as buf:
    np.lib.npyio.format.write_array(buf,
                                    np.asanyarray(v),
                                    allow_pickle=False)
    buf.file.flush()
    zf.write(buf.name, arcname=k + '.npy')
```